# Twint search not working with date parameters (python)

Tags: python, pandas, twint

I'm trying to run a twint search to retrieve a list of tweets, on which I perform sentiment analysis on. I've created a for loop that iterates through a pandas dataframe of dates and runs the twint search with given date parameters.

Here's my code:

```
import twint
import pandas
from textblob import TextBlob

# Functions
def twint_to_pandas(columns): #Creds to Favio Vazques
    return twint.output.panda.Tweets_df[columns]

def getTweets(st, startDate, endDate): #runs a twint search and returns a pandas df
    c = twint.Config()
    c.Search= str(st)
    c.Limit = 20
    c.Lang = "en"
    c.Since = startDate
    c.Until = endDate
    #c.Verified = True
    c.Hide_output = True
    c.Pandas = True
    
    twint.run.Search(c)
    
    df = twint_to_pandas(["date", "username", "tweet"])
    
    return df

def getSentiScore(string):
    t = TextBlob(str(string)) #create a textblob class instance
    score = t.sentiment.polarity # get sentiment
    return score #pass it to next function

def getAverageScore(st, startDate, endDate):
    df = getTweets(st, startDate, endDate) #establish a variable for the fetched tweets
    
    results = [getSentiScore(str(x)) for x in df['tweet']] #list comprehension
    
    resultsDf = pandas.DataFrame(results, columns=['sentiScore']).dropna() #create dataframe for it
    
    mean = resultsDf['sentiScore'].mean() #get a mean sentiment score
    #median = resultsDf['sentiScore'].median()
    #mode = resultsDf['sentiScore'].mode()
    
    print("Mean" + str(mean)) # print the mean
    #print("Median" + str(median))
    #print("Mode" + str(mode))

    
def weeklyScoreToCSV(st, startDate, days):
    datetime = pandas.date_range(start=(str(startDate)), freq='D', periods=days, closed='left')
    datetimeDf = datetime.to_frame(index=False, name='date')
    datesDf = [i for i in (datetimeDf['date'])]
    dateLength = int(len(datesDf)-1)
    for i in range(0, dateLength):
        sentiScore = getAverageScore(st, str(datesDf[i]), str(datesDf[i+1]))
        #print(str(datesDf[i]) + str(datesDf[i+1]))
    
# Execution
#getAverageScore("Obama")
weeklyScoreToCSV("a", '01/01/2019', 10)
```

In the weeklyScoreToCSV function, whenever I input the date parameters for the getAverageScore function call manually, the function works perfectly. However when I attempt to use the given code,

I am given the following **error**

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['date', 'username', 'tweet'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

I cannot figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: which version of Twint are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest version (2.1.20).

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem. Used advanced search feature of twitter to get the search modified as `searchstr = "(search string) until:2021-02-19 since:2021-02-17)"`

I would recommend using all the advanced search syntax from Twitter website and include that in `c.Search = searchstr` rather than including other parameters for `c`.