# How to scrape twitter data from specific years and specific locations using Twint

Tags: python, data-science, screen-scraping, twint

```
import twint 
import nest_asyncio
import pandas as pd


nest_asyncio.apply()

c = twint.Config()
c.Search = "Covid-19"
twint.run.Search(c)
```

The above code collects tweets that have the word covid-19 but I want the tweets only from last year and a specific location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a time range in the search string as follows:

```
searchstr = "(Covid-19) until:2021-02-19 since:2021-02-17)"
c.Search = searchstr
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62554125/twint-search-not-working-with-date-parameters-python)

Comment: NameError: name 'c' is not defined

Comment: Did you define `c = twint.Config()`, as in the question?

Comment: Test show this no longer works. Twitter has changed something.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Do you get an error message? What did Twitter change?

Answer (score 0):

To specify a location, you may add to your search string

```
geocode:latitude,longitude,radius
```

For example:

```
geocode:43.913723261972855,-72.54272478125,150km
```

https://thoughtfaucet.com/search-twitter-by-location/examples/